# How to divide an OpenGL window into multiple windows on the same screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a `cube.c` program which displays a cube that can be rotated using arrow keys. I want to divide the resulting window containing the cube to be divided into multiple(say 4) windows, so that each window contains a part of that cube (top-right, top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left) and each part responds to the rotation using arrow keys in the way they were supposed to when it was a single window. So, if I press right arrow key, the cube should rotate right with corresponding changes visible on every window. Could it be done? 
Here's my `cube.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Function Prototypes
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display();
void specialKeys();

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
// ----------------------------------------------------------
double rotate_y=0; 
double rotate_x=0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// display() Callback function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display(){

  //  Clear screen and Z-buffer
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Reset transformations
  glLoadIdentity();


  // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
  glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );


  //Multi-colored side - FRONT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P1 is red
  glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P2 is green
  glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P3 is blue
  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P4 is purple

  glEnd();

  // White side - BACK
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,  1.0, 1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Purple side - RIGHT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  1.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Green side - LEFT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Blue side - TOP
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Red side - BOTTOM
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// specialKeys() Callback Function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void specialKeys( int key, int x, int y ) {

  //  Right arrow - increase rotation by 5 degree
  if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    rotate_y += 5;

  //  Left arrow - decrease rotation by 5 degree
  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    rotate_y -= 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    rotate_x += 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    rotate_x -= 5;

  //  Request display update
  glutPostRedisplay();

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// main() function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  //  Initialize GLUT and process user parameters
  glutInit(&argc,argv);

   //  Request double buffered true color window with Z-buffer
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

  // Create window
  glutCreateWindow("Rotating Cube");

  //  Enable Z-buffer depth test
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  // Callback functions
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);

  //  Pass control to GLUT for events
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`libtr`](http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html):

> The TR (Tile Rendering) library is an OpenGL utility library for doing tiled rendering. Tiled rendering is a technique for generating large images in pieces (tiles).
>
> TR is memory efficient; arbitrarily large image files may be generated without allocating a full-sized image buffer in main memory.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use both `glScissor()` and `glViewport()` in this program?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want different faces of the cube on different windows. I just want the main window displaying the cube to be split into different parts. Something like this, but on same screen: http://www.geeks3d.com/public/jegx/200810/equalizer-0.5.5.jpg

Comment: I've often found doing some basic linear algebra was superior to `glViewport` and `glScrissors`, after all `OpenGL` is all about transformations.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the edit. But I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want different faces of the cube on different windows. I just want the main window displaying the cube to be split into different parts. Something like this, but on same screen: geeks3d.com/public/jegx/200810/equalizer-0.5.5.jpg

The effect seen there can be achived by using a additional post-projection transformation composed of a scale and a translation. In classic fixed-function GL, such a matrix can simply be pre-multiplied to the projection matrix. So you have to make sure that each window renders the same scene with all the same paramaters at the same time, with only this singe transformation beeing different for each window.

You will have to set up some kind of "total viewport" which would describe the axis-alingend rectangle the application view is to be extended. And then, you can describe each window as sum axis-aligned rectangle with respect to that "total viewport". All you  have to do is to get a scale factor for x and y, and a translation part. Both are easie to find.

On thing you should know is that [equalizer](http://www.equalizergraphics.com/) where your screenhot is of is a *distributed rendering system*, meaning the separate displays are (typically) driven by separate machines connected via network. The general principle stays the same in this setup, but the "render the same things at the same time" part will become much harder. But that stuff is beyond the scope of OpenGL itself. Software like the aforementioned equalizer actually helps you writing such applications.